# solve $|z+2|z=-i$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Before I wrote this question I've tried to solve this by using the definition of $|z|= \sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$ so in this case should be $|z+2|= \sqrt{(a+2)^{2}+b^{2}}$ but this didn't help. I' tried also to use the fact $a=0$ because in $|z+2|z=-i$, there isn't the real part but I don't think this is legit. I think could be useful try the polar form, but I don't really know how to take advantages of this form in this case.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Your statement that a=0 because “there isn’t the real part” is correct and helps to shorten the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|z+2|$ is real, we see that $z=-i/|z+2|$ has no real part, i.e., $z=iy$ for some $y\in\mathbb{R}$. But we now have $|2+iy|iy=-i$, which implies $y\sqrt{4+y^2}=-1$. Squaring this gives $y^2(4+y^2)=1$, or $(y^2)^2+4(y^2)-1=0$, for which the quadratic formula tells us $y^2=-2+\sqrt5$ (rejecting $-2-\sqrt5$ as not the square of a real number). Finally, noting that $y\sqrt{4+y^2}=-1\lt0$ implies $y\lt0$, we have

$$z=iy=-i\sqrt{\sqrt5-2}$$

as the only solution.

Comment: Approved!!!! :-) My steps are very long.

Comment: Thanks, evrythings is clear but why $-2- \sqrt{5}$ is not the square of a real number. Every second grade equation with $\Delta>0$ should have 2 real solution and $-2- \sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{R}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @matteococciniglia, $-2-\sqrt5$ is negative, so it's not the square of anything real.

Answer (score 2):

If $z=a+ib$, $$\left|a+ib+2\right| (a+ib)=-i$$
hence
$$\left(\sqrt{(a+2)^{2}+b^{2}}\right)(a+ib)=-i \tag 1$$

Expand the $(1)$,
$$a\sqrt{a^2+4a+4+b^2}+ib\sqrt{a^2+4a+4+b^2}=0-i$$

and equalize the real part with the real part and the complex part with the complex part. In other word you will calculate two irrational equations.

\begin{cases}
a\sqrt{a^2+4a+4+b^2}=0 & (\star)\\
b\sqrt{a^2+4a+4+b^2}=-1 & (\star\star)
\end{cases}

The $(\star)$ give you $a=0$ being $\sqrt{a^2+4a+4+b^2} \neq 0$ ....and then you can continue....having

$$b\sqrt{4+b^2}=-1$$ with $b\neq 0$.